Is there a classical Lagrangian system with essentially no cyclic coordinates?
Here is what I mean:
In Lagrangian mechanics, we have the equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm d t} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i},\quad i = 1,2, \cdots, n.
$$
and, a cyclic coordinate is the one that is not explicitly included in $L$: e.g., if $q_n$ is a cyclic coordinate, then
$$
L = (q_1, \cdots, q_{n-1},\dot q_1, \cdots, \dot q_{n-1},\dot q_n), \quad \text{and thus}\quad \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_n} = 0.
$$
And what I am curious about is: whether there is a Lagrangian system that essentially has no cyclic coordinates.
"Essentially" means that for any general coordinate system we use, the expression of $L$ contains no cyclic coordinate. This excludes the case of, e.g. the case of Kepler's two body problem, which has cyclic coordinate in Cartesian coordinate system, but have cyclic coordinates in polar coordinate.
If the answer of this question is YES, then furthermore, I am curious what if we limit to the "local" case: we do not search for the coordinate that can cover the entire configuration space, but instead, only consider a local coordinate around a general point, so is there any Lagrangian system that essentially has no cyclic coordinates even we take the local coordinates into consideration?

Editted on Dec 15 2024:
Thanks for @Eli 's reminding. I realized that I need to clarify this:
I assume that $L$ is autonomous (time independent), i.e. it is $L(q, \dot q)$ not $L(q, \dot q, t)$, so that time evolution is a symmetry, and energy $E_L = \sum_{i} \dot q_i \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i} - L$ is conserved. I want to know whether there is some $L$ that has no other continuous symmetries other than this one.

You are looking for the transformation to a non cyclic generalized coordinates ? Why ?

@Eli I didn't mean searching for non cyclic generalized coordinates for a given Lagrangian L. I mean searching for Lagrangian L with no cyclic generalized coordinates, no matter how you choose the general coordinate system. I want to know whether this kind of Lagrangian L exists.

cyclic coordinates means conservation laws, e.g. Angular momentum or linear momentum, thus add a time dependent torque to the system, violating the conservation of the angular momentum

@Eli Yes. This is right. We can break the known symmetries of the problem easily. However, it cannot be guaranteed that there is no other symmetries coming into being after the time-dependent forces or torques are added. And I want to know whether there is a Lagrangian that can be mathematically proved to contain no cyclic coordinates for any general coordinate systems, or we say, no any continuous symmetries described in Noether's Theorem.

Such requirement seems to mean there is no direction in the configuration space, in which directional derivative of $L$ is zero, or in other words, there is no n-tuple $\delta q_k$ for which $\sum_k \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_k}\delta q_k = 0$. This seems mathematically impossible, since to any given vector, there is always some perpendicular vector. In other words, $L$ has some surfaces of constant value, and we can have coordinates for position on the surface, whose change does not mean leaving the surface, and such are cyclic.

@JánLalinský I agree with your intuitive. However, $L$ is not defined on the $n$ dimensional configuration space (we denote it by $M$) but the $2n$ dimensional space (denoted by $TM$, meaning the tangent bundle). What we need here is not a general directional derivative vector field on $TM$, but one induced by the directional derivative vector field on $M$. So, if limiting to this, is there still guarantee that there is some direction at which $L$ remains constant?

@Mr.Egg I think at every point of many dimensional space there has to be a direction in which the function value does not change in the first approximation. For 2D space, $(\partial_x L,\partial_y L)$ defines direction of the largest change per unit step; we have $dL = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}dx +  \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}dy$, so for $(dx,dy) =  \left(-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}dt, \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}dt \right)$ we have $dL=0$. The fact this 2D space may be a subspace of a larger-dimensional space does not seem to matter.

For technical reasons$^1$, let us pose OP's question for Hamiltonian (instead of Lagrangian) systems, i.e. if there always exist a coordinate system in the phase space $M$ so that all position coordinates are cyclic (wrt. to the Hamiltonian $H$)?

Given a fixed point $x_{(0)}\in M$ in phase space, under mild regularity assumptions, there always exists locally (in a sufficiently small open Darboux$^2$ neighborhood of $x_{(0)}$) an $n$-parameter complete solution for Hamilton's principal function
$$S(q^1, \ldots, q^n; P_1, \ldots,P_n; t)$$
to the Hamilton-Jacobi equation, where
$$P_i, \qquad i\in\{1, \ldots, n\},$$
are integration constants. Recall that $S$ is a generating function for a canonical transformation (CT) of type 2. In the new coordinates $(Q^1, \ldots, Q^n;P_1, \ldots, P_n)$, the Kamiltonian $K\equiv 0$ is identically zero, so there all the position coordinates $(Q^1, \ldots, Q^n)$ are cyclic (wrt. to the Kamiltonian $K$), cf. OP's question.

A more interesting question is if there exist globally defined cyclic variables or not? This is intimately linked to integrability, or lack thereof, cf. e.g. this related Phys.SE post.


--
$^1$ For the Legendre transformation between the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalisms, see e.g. this Phys.SE post.
$^2$ A Darboux neighborhood here means a neighborhood where there exists a set of canonical coordinates aka. Darboux coordinates $(q^1, \ldots, q^n;p_1, \ldots, p_n)$, cf. Darboux' Theorem.

Thanks for your answer! This is very close to the answer that I expect. But what I want is exactly the "technical reasons" in the first sentence of your answer: since all Hamiltonians are "locally integrable", what about the Lagrangians? Is there an example that the point transformations always fail to give any cyclic coordinates (even locally), and we have to turn to the more general canonical transformations?

I updated the answer.

Thanks for the update. But the question is not about how to turn Lagrangians into Hamiltonians, but instead, whether there are situations where, if we only allow for transformations allowed in the Lagrangian formulations (i.e. point transformations), then we cannot find any cyclic coordinates, and thus we can only do so by a more general canonical transformations.

A time independent Lagrangian system has time as cyclic coordinate and its corresponding dynamic variable, the energy, is a constant.
The general fact is that any cyclic coordinate corresponds to a conserved quantity in the Poisson algebra.
So the question reduces to: Are there canonical, time independent system of equations motion $$\dot p = -\nabla_q H(p,q), \quad \dot q = \nabla_p H(p,q)$$  that cannot transformed to a Hamiltoniam independent of $q_1:$
$$ H(p_1, \ p_2\dots,\quad q_2, \dots)$$ via a general canonical transformation.
So the answer is no: Any (locally Lipshitz-continuous) n-dimensional canonical system has a (local) solution (in the neighbourhood of the start point in phase space) by a canonical transformation to a set of n constant generalized momentum variables and n cyclic coordinates.
Is this an miracle? No, simply reverse the solution, expressing the start values by the values at later time t (as long as they are partially or completely invertible)
$$p(t)= P(p(t_0),q(t_0),t)   \quad q(t) = Q(p(t_0),q(t_0),t)$$
to
$$p(t_0)=PQ^{-1}(p(t),q(t),t)_p  \quad q(t_0) = PQ^{-1}(p(t),q(t),t)_q$$
By definition all these dynamic variables are independent of t. The difficulty is, that symmetry groups of canonical momentum sets with more than 2 generators are complicated beasts, so that the 3-body problem already does not allow for an algebraic  solution. An algebraic representation  of its hidden constants of motion in terms of the cartesian coordinates and their euclidean momentums defining the free Lagrangian in general does not exist. Numerically no problem, except for error explosion in time.
Numerically then the search for nearly  constant momentum variables and nearly cyclic coordinates is the only way to produce meaningful approximations for macroscopically long times. In astronomy one tries to control the longtime evolution of nearly conserved quantities, eg the slow movement of the perihel or the precession of the angular momentum axis.
So the search for cyclic coordinates and conserved momentums is meaningful: Anything goes, and many solutions of special systems hav been found by very obscure procedures that  try to find a canonical map to a partially solvable system.
